# How to test if an exception was raised and handled in code path?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I am writing an **integration** **test** (not a mocked unit test) to check behavior for the usecase where user doesn't have sufficient permissions to access aws resource say an S3 bucket.

Here is how the code looks like:

```
MyService svcClient = new MyService(permissions);
```

Line above consumes all exceptions(eg. Access Denied to S3 - S3Exception, returns a null object.

While I can certainly test behavior with the following

```
Assertions.assertThrows( NullPointerException.class, () -> svcClient.methodCall());
```

I am not able to express that there was an spectific exception like S3Exception that was raised with the message Access Denied.

## Question:

1. How do I test whether certain exception was **raised and
   handled/consumed** in code path ?
2. If there is no way, is it generally out of scope during integration
   testing to test such behavior and does it fall into behavorial
   testing?

Any guidance here is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Unless you show `MySingletonClass` code, it would be difficult to answer. Also, in your case unit test is easier if you can handle exceptions in another method in `MySingletonClass` class and test that for all those exceptions.

Comment: The question is independent of whether its singleton OR not. I will change the contet on the question to make it more generic.

Comment: you can do that by using assertJ library to assert custom exception. is that what you were asking ?

Comment: No. Custom exceptions are mocked exceptions that you are referring to. This is integration test that is peformed through JUnit where I cannot mock any code line saying when a method is called mock behavior to raise a specific exception.